# Website spoofing our site under different domain. How do I block it?

Tags: security

I've been trying to stop another domain operator from spoofing one of my client's websites and can't figure out how to do it.

Our site is https://autism-products.com and the site spoofing us is https://rubylo.com. If you go to the rubylo.com website you will see they are displaying our website (autism-products.com). It's not redirecting as the domain remains rubylo.com.

They have not replicated the site as changes made to the primary website change immediately on the rubylo.com site, all page code is identical. It does not appear to be an i-frame as I don't see any i-frame code and have added a .htaccess header block to disalow i-frames. I have also added xpath blocks for rubylo.com referral traffic but that does not work either.

The domain is registered with GoDaddy and they are using Cloudflare for DNS hosting. I've contacted both Abuse departments with fraud, copyright and trademark rights complaints but have not received any help.

The base domain of rubylo.com takes you to the replica of the autism-products.com site and completely operates as the site but under the rubylo.com domain. However, the rubylo.com site also has a shopping path with thousands of other products that do not mimic our website. E.g. https://www.rubylo.com/shop/feather-river-doors-36-in-x-80-in-1-lite-unfinished-pine-laundry-woodgrain-interior-door-slab-pine-ready-to-stain-or-paint

The harm is coming as the site operators are defrauding purchasers of products under the rubylo.com/shop/ part of their site and people purchasing from them return to "rubylo.com" and find our website, and assume we are responsible for the purchase and the fraud.

On the /shop/ pages of their site there is some Chinese lettering and if you click on it you are taken to a Chinese website.

I've never seen anything like this and I'm at my wits end trying to stop it. Any guidance from the community would be greatly appreciated! My client is a small family run business inspired to start their company after their son was diagnosed with Autism. They provide products serving the special needs kids community for families and schools throughout the US and they don't need this type of harassment. I would really like to resolve this for them before it causes any serious damage to their business.

Comment: Can you check if they are using a reverse proxy? Are you seeing hits in your server log whenever a page is requested from their site?

Comment: Huh, good thing I googled "is rubylo.com scam", almost ordered GFCI electrical breaker through them but the page looked off and when I entered rubylo.com it sent me to your autism-products and search didn't have anything related to electrical breakers.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller That's a good question Stephen. I can see the Access Logs in WP Engine but I'm not sure how I would tell which request would be originating from their domain. They are using Cloudflare and we are also using Cloudflare so I think it might be hard to determine which request come from Rubylo.com. Ideas?

Comment: @Artem Zinnatullin Yes, it's definitely a scam site. There are some Chinese letters that appear on the Rubylo.com (non Autims-Products.com spoofed pages that take you to a Chinese site of some kind. Also, I have noticed that on the scam pages a different PayPal account comes up almost every time you proceed to their checkout site. People who are getting Scammed by Rubylo.com are then contacting my Client, thinking they are responsible. I've contacted Cloudflare and Godaddy but neither is responding. And, it's actually hard to explain what exactly is going on.

Comment: Can you configure your origin server to log the `X-Forwarded-For` header?  https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/http-request-headers/#x-forwarded-for  for example under Apache: https://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Thanks Stephen, I looked at that doc and don't totally understand how that would work. If you go to rubylo.com, it renders my clients site so the domain remains rubylo.com while it's pulling the exact site in the browser body but not actually forwarding to the autism-products.com domain. I'm sure I'm missing something...

Comment: Cloudflare is sending your origin server data about what domain is requested via that header.  If you can configure your origin server to log it, you could get some visibility into the problem that you don't have right now.